# Gradle sync failed: All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0

Tags: java, android, firebase, admob

I've been going at this for a while now, and it's driving me insane. I've looked through a few existing Stack Overflow questions, but nothing has worked. I keep getting this error whenever I add the last line, which I need for my AdMob ad units. People seem to solve this issue by changing the version number for this line to 15.0.0, but, as you can see, I've already done this. Please help, if you can. Also, this isn't even the first time I've worked with ad units.

Build.gradle (App level)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.coincalc.anduril.sharetale"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Build.gradle (Project level)

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your firebase dependencies to latest version, by changing your dependencies to this:

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'`

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'`

`implementation 'com. google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'`

And in your project level Gradle file, increment your Google services plugin to `4.0.0`

Answer (score 3):

Update the following classpath dependency in your top-level build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Only newer versions of this plugin understand that the new Firebase dependencies no longer all have to be at the same version.

[Read this for more information.](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html)

Comment: The first version of this plugin that works with the new versioning system is 3.3.0. When working with the new versions of Play and Firebase libraries, it should be added to your buildscript classpath dependencies as follows:

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'` (which he is using)

Comment: It was also pretty buggy.

Comment: ohh okay didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
```

into this:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

Check this for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android